# prevent file from being redownloaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a website, on one of its pages a file is automatically downloaded when the page is loaded

How do I prevent the file from being automatically `redownloaded` once he returns to this page in the following conditions

1. user clicks refresh on this page
2. user navigates away from this page, and then clicks the back button to come back to this page ?

Comment: assign the download a unique ID number. if the download is initiated, you invalidate the key and the download script denies any subsequent download attempts.